# Проблема с подключением к Базе данных MySQL

Tags: c#, winforms, mysql-workbench

```
 private void loadBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MySqlCommand auth = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM товары", serverSettings.serverConnection);
                MySqlDataReader rd = auth.ExecuteReader();

                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    this.chart1.Series["Цена"].Points.AddXY(rd.GetString("название_товара"), rd.GetInt32("цена"));
                }
                serverSettings.serverConnection.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Проблема следующая, написал код, чтобы вывести графики, данные которых хранятся в БД MySQL (делал БД в Workbench), но при запуске программы выдаёт ошибку подключения типа
Connection must be valid and open.
Помогите, пожалуйста, я новичок в программировании, не понимаю, что не так... Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Надо открыть сессию. Например mysqlconnection.Open();

Comment: Соединение открыл, но когда делаю какое-то новое действие, то выскакивает ошибка, что соединение уже открыто, как это исправить?

Comment: Закрывай соединение после каждого действия.